# List of PTIJ edits for next season

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

Based on a [recent discussion in the Bam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50530275#50530275), I’m posting this thread to keep track of any needed edits to PTIJ posts. If you see a suggested edit or want to make one yourself, add to an answer here with a link to the post and the edit, and someone will deal with it next Adar.

Comment: Not anticipating that this will be so frequently used, but at least we’ll have this if we need it.

Comment: This may be relevant

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 2020 edits have been completed. Check back here after the season for edits for next year.

Comment: I hate to burst your pre-Purim euphoria but ... since when is Purim based on the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: @DanF Apparently since about two days ago.

Comment: I guess you're **really** starting the Purim laughs early. I see ads for hotel vacations for Rosh Hashanna 2019 (Hmmm ... didn't that occur in January??) and Pesach 2020. But, I have yet to see a hotel ad for Shavuot 2019. I wonder if that's because there is no calendar date for Shavuot?

Comment: "will be removed after they’re completed" @DonielF ?